# Counting occurrences of duplicate items in an array

Tags: c, array

I have to make a simple program that reads `N` integers from the user and counts the occurrences of duplicate items. I know that the chosen sorting algorithm has poor performance, but I chose it for its simplicity.

I'm looking for suggestions for the last part, in which I count the duplicates.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10


int main(void) {
    int i, values[N];
    puts("Insert the values:");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &values[i]);
    }

    /* Sorting */
    int j, tmp, minvalue, minindex;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        tmp = values[i];
        minvalue = tmp;
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (values[j] < minvalue) {
                minvalue = values[j];
                minindex = j;
            }
        }
        values[i] = minvalue;
        values[minindex] = tmp;
    }

    printf("Array is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", values[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    /* Actual counting */
    int dupn = 0, duplicates[N], dupocc[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        dupocc[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (values[i] == values[i - 1]) {
            duplicates[dupn] = values[i];
            if (dupocc[dupn] == 0) dupocc[dupn]++;
            dupocc[dupn]++;
        } else if (dupocc[dupn] > 0) dupn++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dupn; i++) {
        printf("Duplicate %d occurs %d times\n", duplicates[i], dupocc[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that stand out to me immediately in your code. Some good, some are troubling.

### Style

First up, your code is neat, and well structured. Indentation is good, and I even appreciate the fact that you have braced 1-liners and got the space right in your expressions.

Traditionally, C puts the open brace on the new line.... I am not a fan of that, but I don't write C very often, so I stick with a style I use in Java. Just thought I would point that out, though.

### Sorting

Your sort algorithm is ... basic, but effective. I would agree that it is a problem. As a suggestion, you should use an insertion sort, and do the sort at the same time as the `scanf`. That way you load the data in an always-sorted way:

```
puts("Insert the values:");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int val;
    scanf("%d", &val);
    int pos = i;
    while (pos > 0 && values[pos - 1] > val) {
        values[pos] = values[pos - 1];
        pos--;
    }
    values[pos] = val;
}
```

The above will do a shifting insertion sort. Just a suggestion.

### Duplicates.

This is where there are the most significant problems. I would consider your algorithm to be a real overkill one. You can do it all with no extra data, no `duplicates[]` array, etc. A simple loop through the data should be fine.

```
int count = 1;
int previous = values[0] + 1; // something different to the start.
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (values[i] != previous) {
        // something changed... reset the counters
        if (count > 1) {
            // report the count of previous duplicates.
            printf("Duplicate %d occurs %d times\n", previous, count);
        }
        previous = values[i];
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
}
if (count > 1) {
    // catch the last count, if any
    printf("Duplicate %d occurs %d times\n", previous, count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the fact that the insertion sort could be implemented so easily. It really fits the case here. And thanks for the suggestions about the last part, which really was a complicated mess. I changed the code to use a `do`-`while` loop so that I only have to use `printf` once.

Comment: About bracing style, this is a very common flame war, to which there is no correct answer more than you should pick a style and stick to it within a project. Opening brace on the same line is fine, it's called (rather arrogantly) 1TBS and is used by Kernighan and Richie in their famous C book, as well as the Linux kernel, to name only two.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using C99 or higher (definition of `dupn`), so you could also declare your loop counters in place:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

---

I don't really advocate always using curlies after conditional statements anymore, but if you have them for the `if` part then you should put them in the corresponding `else` as well. The same is valid for `if... else-if...` structures.

I do think that statements after a conditional should be on their own line, so that the outline of your program - the level of indent - shows what they are. Right now it looks like you just forgot to indent the following line.

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    if (values[i] == values[i - 1]) {
        duplicates[dupn] = values[i];
        if (dupocc[dupn] == 0) 
            dupocc[dupn]++;
        dupocc[dupn]++;
    } else if (dupocc[dupn] > 0) {
        dupn++;
    }
}
```

---

Whenever you feel the urge to write "banner comments", or "separator comments", such as `/* Sorting */` of `/* Actual counting */`: refactor, create a function. Use what you would have written as banner comment as a function name.

Your `main` is not *very* long, but with such a refactor your program would look like this:

```
void inplace_sort(int *values, int size)
{
    int j, tmp, minvalue, minindex;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tmp = values[i];
        minvalue = tmp;
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (values[j] < minvalue) {
                minvalue = values[j];
                minindex = j;
            }
        }
        values[i] = minvalue;
        values[minindex] = tmp;
    }
}

void values_print(const int *values, int size)
{
    printf("Array is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", values[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void duplicate_count_print(const int *values, int size)
{
    /* These declarations require VLA (c99) */
    int dupn = 0, duplicates[size], dupocc[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dupocc[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (values[i] == values[i - 1]) {
            duplicates[dupn] = values[i];
            if (dupocc[dupn] == 0) 
                dupocc[dupn]++;
            dupocc[dupn]++;
        } else if (dupocc[dupn] > 0) {
            dupn++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dupn; i++) {
        printf("Duplicate %d occurs %d times\n", duplicates[i], dupocc[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i, values[N];
    puts("Insert the values:");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &values[i]);
    }

    inplace_sort(values, N);

    values_print(values, N);

    duplicate_count_print(values, N);

    return 0;
}
```

Look at `main()`, it's very easy to get an overview. I usually also put function prototypes of the sub-functions on top, then `main()` with its body, then the definitions of the sub-functions (which should be made `static`, since no other modules should try to use them).

It is easy to debug your functions if they are separated, short and sweet. They are also more apt to reuse, be replaced, it would be easier to write tests for them. It's easier for your brain if you break down functionality in smaller chunks.

I left the input part for you to refactor.

A problem, as you can see in my comment, is that this requires [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). You could use `malloc` and `free` for these (`calloc` for `dupocc`, so zeroing is done for you), or you could as an alternative keep the array `values` as a global (but give it internal linkage with `static`, no other module should access it), and access it directly without passing it and its size to the functions.

It would also be cleaner to separate the count of duplicates and print to separate functions, but you get the idea.

Comment: You are very correct about the curly braces, I would even go further and even put them even for one liner if or else statements.  Refactoring on one liners without curly braces have a greater chance on making faults when you make it a 2 liner and forgetting to put curly braces.

Comment: Yes, always having braces could have spared us Apple's SSL bug, for example (https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/). I used to always have them, until I started working with Linux more seriously. Nearly everything is an if (since you always always always check return values for errors), so skipping the row with closing bracket has value there. I am aware of the problem and have used always-brackets for years, so I don't think I am likely to make the error too often... but it is a potential hazard.